# 401 in ionic 3 app receive token from local storage to interceptors

Tags: android, angular, ionic-framework, local-storage, angular-http-interceptors

i have the problem that if i switch to a page in my ionic app, the first call is everytime 401. If I reload the page everything works as aspected.

this is my http interceptors:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpEvent, HttpInterceptor, HttpHandler, HttpRequest } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/throw';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';
import { Storage } from '@ionic/storage';

@Injectable()
export class MyAppHttpInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
  token: string;
  constructor(public storage: Storage) {
    storage.get('token').then((val) => {
      this.token = val;
    })
  }

  intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    req = req.clone({
      headers: req.headers.set('Authorization',
        `Bearer ${this.token}`)
    });
    return next.handle(req)
      .catch((error) => {
        return Observable.throw(error);
      }) as any;
  }
}
```

it seems like the storage is to slow. Is it??? Or what is my mistake ^^
I have the problem on all systems: Browser (local storage) and Android.

I get the token from my node-express api with jwt

Comment: of course if i make a req to the api from the app

Comment: You can return a promise from storge (like now) and then inside execute a function with intercept

Comment: I combined booth of Yours (@slashpm & @ Cristian) ideas. thats the solution at the end. THHHAAAANNNKKKKSSSS =)

Answer (score 0):

Well, it is not necessarily slow but `storage.get()` is an async call, so it is very likely that your token variable is still undefined when you execute the http call. You can verify it easily with a breakpoint or with a console.log(this.token).

So I suggest you create a shared **'provider'** (in ionic terms) which stores the token (and you can add all your global variables to it) then inject the provider into the interceptor and simply use the value :)

https://www.joshmorony.com/how-why-and-when-to-use-providers-in-ionic-2/

Comment: Yes sounds like the solution. i give it a try and many thx =)